# Can you justify this "would" in a real conditional

Tags: conditional-constructions

> If we **go** someplace else, it **would** be different, but maybe not as good. (*Seinfeld*)

It is a conditional with *Present Simple* in the conditional clause and *would* in the main clause. It is not correct, as far as I know (*will* should be instead of *would*). Do you know a way to justify it?

Comment: I have been looking for such an example for a while. The last my sentence "If I _give_ you money, **would** you go and buy me some fruit" was refuted, because would was used to express politeness.

Answer (score 6):

In strict usage this should be either

> If we **go** somewhere else it **will** be different ... *or*
>   If we **went** somewhere else it **would** be different.

But informal use is not so demanding. In conversation, sentences have to be constructed "on the fly", without looking so far ahead that strict correspondence can be maintained. The writers/actors here reproduce this very accurately:

> BANYA: You know, Jerry, I was thinking for our next meal, do you think we should come here or should we go someplace else? It has its pros and cons. On the one hand, here, you're guaranteed a great meal. On the other hand --
>   JERRY: Yeah, yeah, I know. This would be good, but it'd be the same. If we go someplace else, it would be different, but maybe not as good. It's a gamble.

The conversation is about choices and contingencies, where it is perfectly normal (and perfectly grammatical) to employ past-form modals with non-past reference. The parties understand what is being said without requiring strict consistency of tenses. Strict form is mandatory only in writing, where the author cannot intervene to correct the reader's misunderstandings and must therefore employ every available convention to insure that no misunderstanding arises.

Comment: What about "If we go somewhere else it **is** different"?

Comment: @Graduate  Form follows context, so this would be very unlikely in this context, where past form has already been established for contingency, and bleeds over into the subsequent consequence: "This **would** be good, but it **'d be** the same" >> "**would be** different". It might occur in a context in which *IF non-past THEN non-past* has already been established: "BANYA: If we stay here, we're stuck with the same old menu. JERRY: But if we go somewhere else, it's different, right."

Comment: What about *if we* **were to go** *somewhere else*?

Comment: @Jim Demands *would*

Comment: It would also be grammatical to say "If we go somewhere else, it will be different", but then it conveys certainty, rather than the possibility for uncertainty.

Answer (score 1):

Correct is

```
If we go someplace else, it will be different, but maybe not as good.
```

The point is that the going happens in the future if it happens.  So the state that will prevail in the event that it happens is a future state.

The only way to justify it is that many English-speaking people are somewhat lax in the attention that they pay to grammar.

Comment: Can I make the statement more general by saying "If we go someplace else, it **is** different, but maybe not as good."?

Comment: No, that's awkward.  I see what you are trying to do, for example "If I go to Walmart, I get crabby" or "If I drink too much my nose turns red."  In such a case, if has the sense of whenever: "Whenever I go to Walmart I get crabby."  I'm not getting that flavor with your sentence.  [Here](http://www1.icsi.berkeley.edu/~kay/bcg/lec07.html) is a good in-depth overview of conditional sentences that you might find helpful.

Comment: Bob, so, if it is true that something can happen in the future, can one apply  to other tenses, present and past, the same conclusions without violating the grammar rules?

Comment: The short answer to your question is yes.  For example, "if I had gone somewhere else, it would have been different" is correct.  For further examples, have a look at the link I posted.

Comment: You're very welcome.

Comment: This does correct the grammar, but it also changes the meaning of the sentence.  It is now a future prediction, rather than being in subjunctive mood, which conveys a sense of uncertainty.

Comment: I don't see the distinction that you are attempting to draw.  There isn't any subjunctive mood in the future in English, because the sense of uncertainty is implied.  If you would care to provide an example, that might help me.