# mixed conditional: present-tense in the if-clause and "would" in the main clause

Tags: conditional-constructions, conditionals

I have seen quite a few mixed conditionals, and I'm wondering whether the following is correct:

> a. If John is in Tokyo now, he would be in a coffee shop.

If the above is correct, how does it differ from b?

> b.  If John is in Tokyo now, he will be in a coffee shop.

Note that in both sentences, the speaker does not know whether John is in Tokyo now. In other words, John may or may not be in Tokyo now.

Next, consider the following:

> Humans have always hoped for infinity, since it **would**/**will** be an awfully lonely universe if we’re the only planet with its porch light on.

How does "would" differ from "will" in this case?

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: (b) is correct. (a) should be "If John _were_ in Tokyo now..."

Comment: Hm. The last sentence would normally read *... would ... if we were*. Using *will* instead of *would* wouldn't convey the same thing. I think *would* is different from other modals in that you could safely use, e.g., *should* and *could* in your first example, but not *would* because it's tied to remote conditionals.

Comment: https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/63678, https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/7863, https://english.stackexchange.com/a/403478